# Angular2 router canActivate after logout

Tags: angular

I used login-guard for some routes (e.g. '/profile'). Looks like this:

```
canActivate() {
    if (this.user.islogin) return true;
    this.router.navigate(['']);
}
```

It redirects user to main page if he's not logged in and tries to get access to some routes. It works fine.
User can log out from any page. I want my app to have next behavior: 
If user is on '/profile' page and clicks 'logout', he should be redirected to main page by canActivate() method. But this method isn't called in this case. What should I do to run canActivate()(reload page, manually call)?
My logout method:

```
logout() {
    localStorage.removeItem('auth_token');
    this.islogin = false;
}
```

I've tried to add `this.router.navigate([this.router.url]);` to logout method, but result is the same. 
Only if I reload page, angular2 redirects me.
What is the right way?

Answer (score 10):

The question is old, but the problem is current.

From Angular v6 you can set the `onSameUrlNavigation` property of the router:

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
    ...
    onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'
})
```

and set `runGuardsAndResolvers` where do you need:

```
{
    path: '',
    component: AccountComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always'
}
```

In your logout method, just call the same route, and the `canActivate` method of your auth guard will be fired:

```
signout(): void {
    this.store.dispatch({
        type: AuthActionTypes.Signout
    });
    // Navigate to the same url to invoke canActivate method
    // in routes with runGuardsAndResolvers.
    // Also activated onSameUrlNavigation router property.
    this.router.navigate([this.auth.redirectUrl]);
}
```

In the sample above, `redirectUrl` is a property where the current url is saved.

Comment: I wasn't known about `runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always'` before.

Answer (score 8):

Considering that your guard just uses `islogin` and that you're setting this to false when the user logs out, the easiest way is to simply redirect upon logout:

```
logout() {
    localStorage.removeItem('auth_token');
    this.islogin = false;
    this.router.navigate(['']);    <---- ADD THIS
}
```

If you want to reuse the logic in `canActivate()` without changing route first, you could do it like this:

First, inject the services wherever your `logout()` is:

```
constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private canActivateGuard: CanActivateGuard) {}
```

(Just use the name you used instead of `CanActivateGuard`)

Next, call it in `logout()`:

```
logout() {
    this.canActivateGuard.canActivate(
        this.route.snapshot,
        this.router.routerState.snapshot);
}
```

Comment: Problem with this is that if you logout on a route that doesn't require that guard, it's going to be run, which is wrong

Comment: Looking at this 2 years later and the answer from robimsim74 is the correct one in my opinion.

Comment: Circular dependency detected

Answer (score 0):

Though an old question I encountered similar issue and I solved it simply by using **async and await**

I am using **Firebase Authentication** with **Angular** using **AngularFireAuth**

When I use the following code:

```
  logout(){
    this.fbAuthService.fbSignOut();
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  }
```

the user is properly signed out but ***this.router.navigate(['/login'])*** does no work! It works if I reload the page.

Later I suspected that I may have to **wait** for the signout process to complete and then call ***this.router.navigate(['/login'])***) function.

So I changed it to:

```
  async logout(){
    await this.fbAuthService.fbSignOut();
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  }
```

And it works like a charm! Hope it helps someone who might stumble upon this.